# Swift : Switching tableview cells in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

How to switch btw cells in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** ?

Do I have to create a `var index = indexpath.row` ?

Comment: What do you mean you need to switch btw cells, do you need to swap the data or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
switch (IndexPath.row) 
  case 0:
        ///// add code here
  case 1:
       //////add code here
  default:
          //////add code here
}
```